# Vue 3 Keyboard Input Sync Issue with API Calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need help as I'm developing an autocomplete component with Vue 3, and I'm encountering a behavior that I can't understand.

My component emits the "update:search" event, which updates the search variable in the parent component, and also the "change" event, which takes the user's input string as a parameter. Both events are triggered on the "keyup" event.

In the parent component, I'm listening for the "change" event of the autocomplete and triggering the search function. At this point, I correctly retrieve my input string, and everything seems to be working well so far. However, when I make an API call, occasionally, what I type on the keyboard is no longer synchronized with what I retrieve in my search function.

Below is an illustration of the issue. When I try to type "hello world"

[image]

Based on my observations, the issue occurs when I modify a property of the autocomplete component from the parent. If I modify a variable that is not used in the Autocomplete component, there is no problem.

You can reproduce the issue by following this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuepic-vue-datepicker-udxicv?file=README.md

Do you have any idea what might be happening?
Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: After some tests I realized that the API calls are not the issue here. Instead the problem is most probably related with the `state` reference. I haven't figured it out yet tho...

Comment: But, when removing the asynchronous call, it works correctly... it's really strange. I also thought about adding a nextTick in the handleInputKeyup method of the autocomplete component, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done it.

I've created a local variable in the component that I'm using on the input v-model, and I'm watching the changes for this variable to emit the update:search event to the parent.

By doing this, there are no more synchronization problems. I just have to make sure that the values of the search prop and the local variable stay in sync.

I've added the working file to the demo repository in case anyone wants to take a look.